# Adding ranges and values VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The first formula is working but the next two formulas are not. Can someone can explain the proper syntax when adding values like this? Like, when to use the ampersand and proper placing of quotations.
Thank in advance.

`Range("F1").Formula = "=(" & Range("I1").Value * 1000 & ")/1000"
Range("D15").Formula = "=(" 1 + Range("D15"").Value * (1 + Range("C15").Value) & )- 1"
Range("E15").Formula = "=("  1 + Range("E15").Value * (1 + Range("C15").Value) & ")- 1"`

Comment: First thing I notice is an extra quote here `Range("D15"").Value`

Comment: The first formula is right, bare in mind that you need to write your formula as a String. And if you write some variable, it should be "string" `& variable_calculation + 1 &` "string"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to fix it - you are missing ampersands:

```
Range("F1").Formula = "=(" & Range("I1").Value * 1000 & ")/1000"
Range("D15").Formula = "=(" & 1 + Range("D15").Value * (1 + Range("C15").Value) & ")- 1"
Range("E15").Formula = "=(" & 1 + Range("E15").Value * (1 + Range("C15").Value) & ")- 1"
```